# showing link in Html.fromHtml() which navigate to different activity or fragment

Tags: android

In the string.xml file, I have Html text which has link and images, I have successfully shone the image store in my drawable folder, but showing the link which navigates from that activity to another is where I am having trouble

**for setting text in text view**

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.my_local_string), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT), new Html.ImageGetter() {
                    @Override
                    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                        int id;
                        if (source.equals("myPic.jpg")) {
                            id = R.drawable.myPic;
                        } 
                        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
                        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        return d;
                    }
                }, null));
```

**in string.xml file**

```
<string name="my_local_string<[CDATA[<imgsrc="myPic.jpg"/<br/<br/<a href="">MyLink</a><br/><a href="">MyAnotherLink</a><br/> ]]></string>
```

I have to detect click on both link

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. When you say "link which navigates from activity to another", do you mean, navigates to another activity in the app (or) navigates to the link url in a browser (or) external application?

Comment: @ChrisvinJem navigate means to move simply from one activity to another, I have to detect that click action on the link so that proper intent can be pass and move to another activity

Comment: You need to parse your html text, put it in `SpannableStringBuilder`, get the `URLSpan` and replace it with `ClickableSpan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the HTML string into `SpannableStringBuilder`, find the .. span using `URLSpan`, remove that span and replace it with your custom `ClickableSpan`. You can start the new activity in it's `onClick`. You'll need to do something along the following lines.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = (SpannableStringBuilder) Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.my_local_string), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, new Html.ImageGetter() {
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        int id;
        if (source.equals("myPic.jpg")) {
            id = R.drawable.myPic;
            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(id);
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return d;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}, null);
URLSpan[] spans = builder.getSpans(0, builder.length(), URLSpan.class);
//Keep track of the links
int i=0;
for (URLSpan span : spans) {
    int start = builder.getSpanStart(span);
    int end = builder.getSpanEnd(span);
    builder.removeSpan(span);
    //Assign the value to a final variable so that it can be used inside the onClick
    //to determine which link was clicked.
    final int finalI = i;
    builder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("main", "link clicked");
            String message;
            if (finalI == 0) {
                //First link
                message = "First link clicked";
            } else {
                //Second link, and so on
                message = "Second link clicked";
            }
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } }, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    i++;
}
textView.setText(builder);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

```
<string name="my_local_string"><![CDATA[<imgsrc="myPic.jpg"/><br/><br/><a href="">MyLink</a><br/><a href="">MyAnotherLink</a><br/>]]></string>
```

Comment: how this will work if I have more link in the same text, I have edit the question, in my_local_string there are two links, I want to know which link was clicked

Comment: Use some unique value(for eg, keep track of the iteration count and use that to differentiate) in the `onClick` listener to differentiate the links, I've updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: thanks, getURL method also works for me, I have accepted your answer